# "mysql_native_password" failed, cant reach to the server (ASP.NET)

Tags: mysql, asp.net

I am creating an ASP.NET web page , and when performing an insert , the program gives me the following error:

[image: msql_native_password error]

My code is this:

```
 Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
 Imports MySql.Data

 Partial Class RegistracionNueva
 Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

 Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim conexion As New MySqlConnection
    Dim adapter As MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim consulta, nombre, apellido, sexo, nacimiento, pais, telefono, email, pass As String
    nombre = Request.Form("nombre")
    apellido = Request.Form("apellido")
    sexo = Request.Form("radio1")
    nacimiento = Request.Form("fechanac")
    pais = Request.Form("Pais")
    telefono = Request.Form("pref") + Request.Form("telefono")
    email = Request.Form("correo")
    pass = Request.Form("pass")
    conexion.ConnectionString = "server=XXX;database=XXX;user id=XXX;password=XXX"
    Try       
        consulta = "Insert into Clientes('Nombre','Apellido','Sexo','Fecha_Nacimiento','Pais','Telefono','Email','Contrasena')VALUES('" & nombre & "','" & apellido & "','" & sexo & "','" & nacimiento & "','" & pais & "','" & telefono & "','" & email & "','" & pass & "')"
        conexion.Open()
        adapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexion)
        conexion.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString())
        conexion.Close()
    End Try
    Server.Transfer("Registrado.aspx", True)
End Sub
End Class
```

I thought that may not be the connection that is giving me problems ... who knows my query or any procedure is incorrect .

What should I add or change ?

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it's your connection string. It shouldn't have a space in it, for one. Try:

```
"server=XXX;database=XXX;uid=XXX;pwd=XXX"
```

Comment: I don't know asp.net but it looks like the syntax you're using to initialize the connection string isn't working. I'd try: connexion = new MySqlConnection("server=XXX;database=XXX;user id=XXX;password=XXX") as the syntax instead.

Comment: it was a good idea... but the code still not working.. i reset my database user and password so much.. annd still saying that error.. I Cant understand why :/

Answer (score 0):

Sorry , I could solve it already ! The problem was the same server, I told my problem to the owner of the account (the server) and asked me my IP address .. now I can safely access !

Thank you all!